# LWC Lookup does not return value for different language

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, sql, translation-workbench

We have a screen flow hosted on SF Community Site with language option as English , Spanish ,Portugues & Creole . One of the screen has a lookup (LWC component) which displays list of records and the query is written in a Apex class handler.  The lookup shows result when English and Creole is selected, but when Spanish & Portuguese is selected the results don't show up. I checked the query in debug log and query gives result for English and Creole but same query does not return result when Spanish & Portuguese is selected.

Class -

```
public with sharing class LwcLookupHandler {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static List<sobject> findRecords(String searchKey, String objectName, String customFilter, String programId) {  
        string searchText = '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchKey) + '%\'';  
        string whereStatement = ' WHERE pmdm__Program__c = :programId  AND Organization_Account__r.Name LIKE ' + searchText    ;
       // string whereStatement = ' WHERE Organization_Account__r.Name LIKE ' + searchText    ;
            if (customFilter != '' )whereStatement += ' AND ' + customFilter;
            string queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name, pmdm__Status__c, pmdm__Program__c, Organization_Account__r.Name FROM ' + objectName + whereStatement + ' LIMIT 6 ' ; 
            System.debug('Query: '+ queryString); 
            return Database.query(queryString);
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.